# Custom Button URL using an IF condition

Tags: custom-button, error, url

I am trying to create a custom URL button in salesforce and when hitting save getting the below error:

> Error: Enter a URL that is valid and well-formed

This is the formula I am using:

```
{
!IF( 
AND(
Project__c.RecordType  = 'Minor Works Project',
{!NOT(!ISPICKVAL(Project__c.Type__c, 'Training'))})
,
URLFOR("https://datacom--uat.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Report/00Op0000000cBzHEAU/view?", null, 
    [fv1=Project__c.Client_Contact__c]),
 {!IF( 
AND (
Project__c.RecordType  = 'Minor Works Project',!ISPICKVAL(Project__c.Type__c, 'Training')
),
URLFOR("https://datacom--uat.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Report/00Op0000000cBzHEAU/view?", null, 
    [fv1=Project__c.Client_Contact__c]), 
URLFOR("https://datacom--uat.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Report/00Op0000000cBzHEAU/view?", null, 
    [fv1=Project__c.Client_Contact__c]))}
)
}
```

PS: I just copied the URLFOR statement from a previous Help article. I am not sure why and if there is a need for the `Null` in the URL I used

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the extraneous `{!` and `}`. Once you start and close a formula with `{!` and `}` no other merge field syntax is required

Just looking at the first 5 lines, you have

```
{
!IF( 
AND(
Project__c.RecordType  = 'Minor Works Project',
{!NOT(!ISPICKVAL(Project__c.Type__c, 'Training'))})  <== remove merge syntax
...
```

you need

```
{
!IF( 
AND(
Project__c.RecordType  = 'Minor Works Project',
NOT(ISPICKVAL(Project__c.Type__c, 'Training')))
...
```

*as an aside, these complex formulas are best debugged by starting with the smallest formula, confirming it compiles/works, then adding pieces in one at a time*

*Also, use relative references in your `URLFOR` to make it easier to deploy - though the hardcoded reportIds will also yield deployment issues*